# Creating a dynamic formula in vba with a variable in it

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create a VBAformula that will fill excel with a formula.
i've got this VBA code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim u As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet

u = 9

Dim used As Range
Set used = ws.UsedRange

Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = used.Row + used.Rows.Count - 2
ws.Range("K4:K" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(R4C2-R4C" & u & ")/10"
```

but in excel I get this formula:
=($B$4-$I$4)/10

is it possible with this code to get the formula looking like this?
=(B4-I4)/10
without the $ symbol?

Comment: You are using R1C1 notation with absolute addressing. That corresponds to `$` signs in the A1 notation. If you want relative addressing, don't use absolute addressing in R1C1 to being with. A relative address in R1C1 has the form of `R[4]C[2]`, but you will have to correct the numbers because they are relative to where you put the formula.

Comment: Sidenotes, you might be specific about which worksheet to use instead of `ActiveSheet`. There are also [better ways to search for a last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/9758194).

Comment: @GSerg. Works. I Need to make it dynamic. I didn't know how buy thanks to you, I know now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer `.Formula` over `.FormulaR1C1` here:

```
 ws.Range("K4:K" & lastRow).Formula = "=(B4-I" & u & ")/10"
```

Also important: use `Long` instead of `Integer` to avoid a possible Overflow error:

```
 Dim lastRow As Long
```

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure exactly what the final version of the formula should be in each successive column, but perhaps you're looking for the following:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 3
     ws.Range("K4:K" & lastRow).Offset(, i * 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[]C2-R[]C[-" & u & "])/10"
Next
```

This keeps the `B` absolute and the rows and other column relative.

Comment: That works, but the I column will also chance. After column I IT will go to column R and other columns after that

Comment: What is the column logic then? That is not in your original question.

Comment: Column logic is column +7 column and that 4 Times (in a loop i hot figured out)

Comment: Does `B` change as well or should that be absolute?

Comment: B should be static

Comment: @Ultiseeker see the edit. I'm not sure if that's what you're going for. It keeps the $B absolute and the columns and rows relative.

Comment: Works as well. GSerg also provided a great answer.